# How to link and include PhysX 4.0 Extensions Library?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, lib, physx

I am including the PhysX 4.0 SDK into my C++ opengl project, but I cannot use anything from the PhysX Extensions library like `PxDefaultErrorCallback` or `PxDefaultMemoryOutputStream` because I need to include the Extension library first. The problem is I cannot find the `PhysXExtensions32.lib` and its DLL in any folder of the PhysX SDK that I have compiled myself.

I could find a static library called `PhysXExtensions_static_32.lib`, but when linking against this library I get this error:

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in file.obj.
```

Is there a way I can get the Extension libaray as `Multithreaded-Debug-DLL (/MDd)` instead of a `Multithreaded (/MT)`?

```
I link against these libraries:
- PhysX_32.lib
- PhysXCommon_32.lib
- PhysXCooking_32.lib
- PhysXFoundation_32.lib

I redistribute these DLL files:
- PhysX_32.dll
- PhysXCommon_32.dll
- PhysXCooking_32.dll
- PhysXFoundation_32.dll
- PhysXGpu_32.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer on a duplicate of this question on the PhysX 4 Github repo and it is working now:
https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/PhysX/issues/115